# Magento2: Import custom options from product programmatically

Tags: magento2, import, custom-options

I want to import custom options from  existing product programmatically.My custom options are copied but options having values are not imported.It throws invalid option value error.

I am using below code:

```
  $customOptions = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

    try {

        if (count($customOptions->getData()) > 0) {
            foreach ($customOptions->getData() as $key => $value) {
                $output[] = $this->array_except($value, ['option_id', 'product_id', 'sku']);
            }
            foreach ($output as $arrayOption) {
                $this->createOption($arrayOption, $product);
            }
        }
 public function createOption($arrayOption, $product)
{
    try {
        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        //$product->save($product);
        $option = $this->_option
            ->create()
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
            ->addData($arrayOption);
        $option->save();
        $product->addOption($option);
        $product->save();
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('The custom options cannot be assigned to the product.' . $e->getMessage())
        );
    }

}
```